# How to read and write Object Arrays in JAVA ? I am facing Problems

Tags: java, arrays, object, io

I am having 10 Classes and I Have linked them like that 
class Person is linked in class Array ,I have taken an array of objects in Array Class like this

```
Person [] p = new Person[99];

public void generate(){

  for(int i=0;i<=p.length-1;i++)
  {
     p[i]=new Person();//this will allocate space for Persons
  }
}
```

Now how can i write the Data of each index stored by some Other class ?
and How can i read after terminating it.?
Thanks indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the element of an array, you can simply use the index of an element:

```
Person perfonFromIndex = p[index];
```

If you want to store objects, of different types in same array, you can declare this array of type from which all of your classes are derived, for example Object class:
Object[] p = new Object[99];

```
public void generate(){
  for(int i=0;i<p.length;i++)
  {
     p[i]=new Person();//this will allocate space for Persons
  }
}
```

But in that case, you have to cast every time you want to get an element of sepcified class:

```
SpecifiedClass perfonFromIndex = (SpecifiedClass)p[index];
```

It's quite bad sollution.
Better thing is to achieve it by using polymorphysm:

```
class Base{
    void method(){
        System.out.println("from Base");
    }
}
class Derived1 extends Base{
    @Override
    void method(){
        System.out.println("from Derived1");
    }
}
class Derived2 extends Base{
    @Override
    void method(){
        System.out.println("from Derived2");
    }
}
```

Since now, you won't have to cast every time, you want to call the method() of specified time, java compiler will know which method should be invoked:

```
Base[] arr = new Base[3];
arr[0] = new Base();
arr[1] = new Derived1();
arr[2] = new Derived2();
for(Base b : arr){
    b.method();
}
```

And the output is:

```
from Base
from Derived1
from Derived2
```

For more about polymorphism you can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Comment: Thanks I will do this bro but !
I have already stored data ... Now All i have to do is ... I want to write that stored data on disk ... import java.io.*; Since I don't know how to use io . Please if you can Explain that Briefly.

Comment: Here is great tutorial how to do such things: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-fileoutputstream-example/

Comment: Will it work for Object Arrays ?

Comment: yes, it will. Please, accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Sure Bro and Thank you  :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of storing your data on disk. One *generic* approach is the `outputstream`:

```
/**
 *
 * @param object  - the object you want to store on disk
 * @param path    - the path where to store it (e.g: "c:\MyFiles\")
 * @param fileName - any name you like (e.g: "myArray.me")
 */   
public static void saveFile(Object object, String path, String fileName){
    FileOutputStream fileOutPutStream = null;  // this stream will write the data to disk
    try{
        File newPath;   // a File object can be a file or directory in Java
        newPath = new File(path);  // this File object will represent the parent folder where you store your data
        newPath.mkdirs();  // let's create the directory first (in case it doesn't exist yet)

        fileOutPutStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(path, fileName));  // this will open the output stream to a file in your directory
        try(ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutPutStream)){  // try-with-resources will make sure your object output stream closes in the end (even on exceptions)
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(object); // this will actually write the object to the object outputstream
        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){   // shouldn't happen when you created your directories earlier
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Couldn''t save file {0} due to {1}", new Object[]{fileName, ex.toString()});
    }catch(IOException ex){   // thrown on any other input output problem 
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Couldn''t save file {0} due to {1}", new Object[]{fileName, ex.toString()});
    }finally{  // in any case, always close the file output stream afterwards
        try{
            fileOutPutStream.close();  // closes even when an exception was thrown
        }catch(IOException | NullPointerException ex){  // when closing, other errors can happen
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Couldn''t close file {0} due to {1}", new Object[]{fileName, ex.toString()});
        }
    }
}
```

You can now use this method like this:

```
Integer[] myNumbers = ...;
saveFile(myNumbers, "arrays", "number.array");
```

It will store the array `myNumbers` in a subdirectory of your program called "arrays" and name the file "number.array". You can of course use absolute paths as well: "c:\myFiles\arrays" or relative paths like "..\arrays" to go one directory "up".

And this is how you can load the files again:

```
 /**
 *
 * @param <T>  the type of your object that will be returned (e.g. int[])
 * @param path - as above, the directory where you stored the file
 * @param fileName  - the name of the file
 * @param objectType - the type of your object (e.g: int[].class)
 *
 */
 public static <T> T loadFile(String path, String fileName, Class<T> objectType){
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;  // instead of file output stream, an input stream
    T object = null;   // it's generic, so we don't know what type the return object will have - that's why we call it T
    try{
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(path, fileName)); // will open the file input stream for us
        try(ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream)){  // again, try-with-resources to get an Object input stream from the file input stream
            object = (T) objectInputStream.readObject();  // reads the object and casts it to T 
        }catch(IOException ex){
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Couldn''t load file {0} due to {1}", new Object[]{fileName, ex.toString()});
        }
        return object;  // returns the freshly read object
    }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Couldn''t load file {0} due to {1}", new Object[]{fileName, ex.toString()});
    }finally{
        if(fileInputStream != null){
            try{
                fileInputStream.close();
            }catch(IOException ex){
                logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Couldn''t close file {0} due to {1}", new Object[]{fileName, ex.toString()});
            }
        }
        return object;  // might be null in case there was an error
    }
}
```

Full example usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] array = new int[2];
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 2;
    saveFile(array, "arrays", "number.array");

    int[] array2 = loadFile("arrays", "number.array", int[].class);
    for(int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
        System.out.println("" + array2[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: applicable for Object arrays ?

Comment: an array itself is already an object (..sort of) see my update.

Comment: I added a load method and a better example on how to use them

Comment: Okay Thank you so much !